# Digital Ocean Kubernetes: Nodeport not accessible from browser

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, digital-ocean, service-node-port-range

I have set up a k8s cluster (1 node cluster) using DOKS. The service is running fine with nodeport config. However, I am unable to access it using `http://${NodeIP}:${NodePort}` from browsers. I have even tried to add the firewall rule, but i am getting `error response from backend` while trying to add a new inbound TCP rule. Not a useful error message!

Curl and Telnet are failing as well.

Please find below my dockerfile, deployment and service yaml files.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.21.1
COPY build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**Service YAML file**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: int
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31000
  selector:
    app: int
```

**Deployment YAML**

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: int
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: int
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: int
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: int
          image: registry.digitalocean.com/xxxxx/int:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
      restartPolicy: Always
```

**Kubectl get pods output**

```
root@ast-a1:~# kubectl get pods
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
int-7cc5445c7-hnwvp      1/1     Running   0          3h14m
int-7cc5445c7-qtr6n      1/1     Running   0          3h14m
```

**Kubectl get svc output**

```
root@ast-a1:~# kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
int          NodePort    10.xxx.xx.xx    <none>        80:31000/TCP   152m
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.xxx.x.x      <none>        443/TCP        3d3h
```

**The response**

[image]

Am I making a mistake somewhere? I am just trying out DOKS.

EDIT:

Added tracert output.

```
C:\Users\ck5>tracert 1xx.xx.xx.xxx

Tracing route to 1xx.xx.xx.xxx over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     4 ms     2 ms     3 ms  1x.1xx.xx.xx.static-hydrabad.vsnl.net.in [1x.1xx.xx.xx]
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5    49 ms    52 ms    12 ms  2xx.6x.xxx.xxx.static-bangalore.vsnl.net.in [2xx.xx.xxx.xxx]
  6    13 ms    12 ms   110 ms  1xx.1xx.2xx.15
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

Comment: your service is running and are you getting output ? did you tried to debug first POD is up & running and getting output from service using kubectl port-forward command.

Comment: This is probably a firewall rule issue- you should talk more about how you tried to allow inbound traffic and how you got that error message.

Comment: @HarshManvar I have added pods availability status in the question. The service is also up.

Comment: @PaulBecotte I have tried to use digital ocean's firewall portal to add a new TCP inbound rule. But it is not allowing me to add a rule with the error as described in the question.

Comment: how you verified service is up ? using just POD running so ? there is no readiness liveness probes also in deployment config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a security group or a firewall issue. Run a traceroute to the destination IP from the machine with your browser.

If it stops at the last hop, it is most likely the security group not allowing connections to your port from the source subnet.

If the traceroute stops in the middle it is more likely a firewall issue.

Comment: I have added a tracert

Comment: Looks like a firewall issue to me.

Comment: the digital ocean service is not allowing me to add a firewall entry with some backend error.

Comment: thats like a drop in the ocean!

Comment: I have added the firewall rule. Now i am able to access the application. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First tried to verify your service is up & running or not using the port-forward command

```
kubectl port-forward svc/int -n <Namepsace name> 8080:80
```

open the `localhost:8080` in the browser

this way you can first verify if running is running and giving output or not.

also I hope the config you are adding inside the **Nginx** docker image for proper, check the log of pod also once to verify no issue in POD.

Now if service is giving output there is an issue from the `Nodeport` side now or from the `firewall` side.

Comment: It is not accessible from the browser. However, I have added tracert output. I hope that's helpful.

Comment: It was a firewall issue. Now i am able to access the application from the browser.